# pandas dropna() doesn't work if you load csv in chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading in a ~24GB csv file using chunksize

```
reader = pd.read_csv(in_file, chunksize=10000)

for chunk in reader:
    chunk.dropna(inplace=True)
    ...
```

The problem I am running in is that the csv file still has null values. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: What do you mean *"the csv file still has null values"*? You only removed `na` values from the chunk. Did you write that to a file afterwards?

Comment: You might consider to split your csv in smaller file from terminal and tthen use `dask` to read it.

Comment: `df = df.dropna()` did do the trick.

Comment: @kabanus I did save out the file afterwards and read it back in to make sure that there are no `na` values using `dask`.

Comment: Seems like a bug if  `chunk = chunk.dropna()` and `chunk.dropna(inplace=True)` do not result in the same thing.

Comment: @kabanus seems so. Especially painful when you try to use the csv file to train your model with keras later on and you get an unrelated error.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was

```
reader = pd.read_csv(in_file, chunksize=10000)

for chunk in reader:
    chunk = chunk.dropna()
    ...
```

Thanks for the help @kabanus and @user32185. I also used dask to help with the file size.

Comment: I suggest being a good citizen and opening a ticket on the [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). Maybe the next person will not suffer what you had to go through!

Comment: ticket can be found here 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25451